# SocketInputStream.socketRead0 - hangs while client sending request to server using jax rs

Tags: java, glassfish, jax-rs, jersey-client

Im using javax.ws.rs.client to send a request to a web service and once in a while we get the thread hangs and we have to restart the process.

Im familiar with few jdk bugs fixed and we are using jre 8 251 that should contain fixes to similar problems ive found.

We are using javax.ws.rs-api-2.1,jersey-client-2.26. Let me know if other dependencies needed.

```
"pool-1-thread-1" #22 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001979b800 nid=0x1ae4 runnable [0x000000001ad7e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x00000000c05df118> (a java.lang.Object)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x00000000c05e11a0> (a sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x00000000c05e11b8> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x00000000c05e1210> (a sun.net.www.protocol.https.DelegateHttpsURLConnection)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x00000000c05e1210> (a sun.net.www.protocol.https.DelegateHttpsURLConnection)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector._apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:390)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:282)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:278)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.lambda$invoke$0(JerseyInvocation.java:753)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$$Lambda$89/1655661149.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:229)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:414)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:752)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:445)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.post(JerseyInvocation.java:351)

    at my code executing a request to web service

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Not hung. Blocked. The thread is blocked in the read, waiting for the response. So the server isn't responding. You need to set a client read timeout somehow to catch this case.

Comment: Well it is blocked for days. I did set the client properties:client.property(ClientProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, connectTimeOut * MILLIES_PER_SEC);
  client.property(ClientProperties.READ_TIMEOUT, readTimeOut * MILLIES_PER_SEC);  but it does not help